# counting lengths of the words in a .txt

Tags: python

I have seen similar questions but nothing that truly helped me.  I need to read in a text file, split it, and count the lengths of the words. I am also trying to print them out in a table with the length of the word on the left and then the actual word on the right. My code is all screwed up right now cause I got to the point where I decided to ask for help.

```
a = open('owlcreek.txt').read().split()
lengths = dict()
for word in a:
    length = len(word)

if length not in lengths:
    for length, counter in lengths.items():
        print "Words of length %d: %d" % (length, counter)

#words=[line for line in a]
#print ("\n" .join(counts))
```

Also I guess I will need to write a little parser to get all the `"!--` out. I tried to use **The Counter**, but I guess I don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: What do you mean by `'"!--'`?

Comment: Is there only one word of each length or do you need to put more thought into the layout of your table?

Comment: by '"!--' I mean all the apostrophes and dashes and all that out since the owlcreek.txt is a story and in its original form, I need it to print out every word and its length, or every word once and its length. There is no need for a one word per length restriction.

Comment: You mean the punctuation then. And what is **the counter** you speak of?

Comment: Counter as in Counter(map(len, words))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
a=open('owlcreek.txt').read().split()
lengths=dict()
for word in a:
    length = len(word)
    # if the key is not present, add it
    if not lengths.has_key(length):
        # the value should be the list of words
        lengths[length] = []
    # append the word to the list for length key
    lengths[length].append(word)

# print them out as length, count(words of that length)
for length, wrds in lengths.items():
    print "Words of length %d: %d" % (length, len(wrds))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nope i need it to print out the actual words. like 3 Owl, 5 Creek, 12 superstition, but in a table form of course

Comment: You have everything you need, instead of printin the count, do a nested for loop to iterate through the list of values printing the words in them.

Answer (score 0):

A simple regular expression will suffice to clear out the punctuation and spaces.

edit: If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you want all the unique words in a text file, sorted by length. In which case:

```
import re
import itertools

with open('README.txt', 'r') as file:
    words = set(re.findall(r"\w+'\w+|\w+", file.read())) # discard duplicates
    sorted_words = sorted(words, key=len)

for length, words in itertools.groupby(sorted_words, len):
    words = list(words)
    print("Words of length {0}: {1}".format(length, len(words)))
    for word in words:
        print(word)
```

Comment: Nope i need it to print out the actual words. like 3 Owl, 5 Creek, 12 superstition, but in a table form of course

Comment: for every single word i need there to be a digit next to it that says how many characters it has...... this is very, very close because it prints out words with 17 characters followed by a list of words with 17 characters. i can probably get there from here though.